From PowerBI to PowerAutomate to DB Sql Server Module
I have successful get out the table from the powerbi DAX copy (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HMAMtYYcS7M)
and send it in a email But i need to move the data into a Database table (SQL Server).
and i dont know how to get the values from the powerbi connection quary
into the columns in the SQL Server module

This part under might be wrong

